# Access Runtime 2013 app with liked tables shuts down on startup

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I've written an application in Access 2013 (64-bit) that I'd like to split into front-end and back-end databases, storing the back-end on a file server where multiple machines can access the data via local instances of the front-end.  None of the computers have Access installed, so I'm using Access Runtime 2013 on them.

The application runs fine when it is not split, on a single computer.  As soon as I split the app into front-end/back-end files, the program opens and immediately closes on startup, with no error messages.  I'm assuming that this is due to invalid links to the external data file on the first startup of the app (i.e. existing links are to folder locations on my development machine).

Has anyone experienced this problem? If so, is it due to invalid links?  And, what can I do to allow the program to stay open, allowing the user to navigate to a form that I've provided in the main menu form for setting the path to the back-end file for re-linking tables?

Comment: Sounds like you have the main menu form set as your database start form.  Is there anything in that form which tries to retrieve data from any of the linked tables?

Comment: Thanks, Hans, but I'm not loading any data on startup on the Main Menu.  It's basically a switchboard with several buttons for navigating to various reports & data-driven forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the load event for the menu form check if you can access the data by trying to open a recordset. If you can't, close the menu form and open your form for setting the database location. Make that there's nothing on you location setting form that is bound to the database.